# Creating List of values as field

Tags: mysql

I am mysql newbie, trying to do something like that:
I need a table which could hold unlimited amount of users id and I thought that I could do this like that:

```
TABLE USER FIELDS:
user_id - PK
group_id - FK
TABLE GROUP FIELDS:
group_id - PK
user_id - FK
```

Sure it won't work since Primary Keys are unique so I'v got now 1:1 relation with totally nothing,
I was trying to not seting group_id as PK than I could have something like n:n relation but you can't create Foreign Key on NOT UNIQUE field so it's impossible.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: I agree that our data structure looks non-sensical -- having multiple tables with the same columns is usually a sign of poor design.  It is entirely unclearly what you want to do, though.

Comment: I think should you remove `user_id` from the groups table. The groups table will hold data about the group's name, its privileges etc, but not who's a member of it. To make a user a member of your group, enter the group id in the `group` column in the user table.

Comment: To find out who's in a specific group, you could still run a query like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE group_id = 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It absolutely unclear from your question what your end goal is, but in case you're looking for a way to create N:N relation between users and groups you can do it by introducing a pivot table like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE users
(
  user_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  user_name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE groups
(
  group_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  group_name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE group_user
(
  group_id INT NOT NULL,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (group_id, user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES groups (group_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
);
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2852b/1)** demo

Comment: Hey ! It's looks like your unswer is fine and working, is it good practice to make tables like that?

Comment: Hey! It is perfectly fine when you need to model N:N relationships.

Answer (score 0):

if each user belongs to one group, then you just need to remove the user id from the group table, as follows:

```html
TABLE USER FIELDS:
user_id - PK
group_id - FK

TABLE GROUP FIELDS:
group_id - PK
```

if you intend for each user to belong to many groups then the join table as illustrated by peterm answer is the way to go.

Comment: Right ! But i need many users in many groups, thanks for help : )